# What is the difference between AIC() and extractAIC() in R?

Tags: r, regression, aic, stepwise-regression

The R documentation for either does not shed much light. All that I can get from [this link](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-December/147855.html) is that using either one should be fine. What I do not get is why they are not equal.

Fact: The stepwise regression function in R, `step()` uses `extractAIC()`.

Interestingly, running a `lm()` model and a `glm()` 'null' model (only the intercept) on the 'mtcars' data set of R gives different results for `AIC` and `extractAIC()`.

```
> null.glm = glm(mtcars$mpg~1)
> null.lm = lm(mtcars$mpg~1)

> AIC(null.glm)
[1] 208.7555
> AIC(null.lm)
[1] 208.7555
> extractAIC(null.glm)
[1]   1.0000 208.7555
> extractAIC(null.lm)
[1]   1.0000 115.9434
```

It is weird, given that both the models above are the same, and `AIC()` gives the same results for both.

Can anyone throw some light on the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two differences for a usual linear regression model (`lm`) between `AIC` and `extractAIC`:

- `AIC` accounts for the estimation of the unknown variance of the error (i.e., scale) while `extractAIC` does not, hence $k$ is one less with `extractAIC`.
- `AIC` uses the formula $n\log\frac{RSS}{n}+n+n\log\left(2\pi\right)$ for the -2 log likelihood, while `extractAIC` drops the additive constant, and uses only $n\log\frac{RSS}{n}$. (At least by default; you can set a custom scale.)

Of course, none of these matters, if the values are only used in comparison.

In addition to these, and as already noted above, `extractAIC` behaves differently for `lm` and `glm` (in contrast to `AIC`!), namely, it uses the above formula only for `lm`, for `glm` it switches to the `aic` function of the fitted model, which is different.

Comment: The socond point does not seem to be correct, because `AIC` does not compute the log likelihood at all, but calls the `logLik` method on the model. Example: `> m <- lm(mpg ~ disp, data=mtcars)
> ll <- logLik(m)
> -2*as.numeric(ll) + 2*attr(ll, "df")
[1] 170.2094
> AIC(ll)
[1] 170.2094
> extractAIC(m)
[1]  2.00000 77.39732
`

Comment: @cdalitz "AIC does not compute the log likelihood at all, but calls the logLik method on the model" That is correct. But for `lm` (to which my two points refer), the formula used is just the one I have given: compare `32 * log(stats:::deviance.lm(m)/32)+32+32*log(2*pi)` with `-2*ll` in your example.

Answer (score 6):

According, to the help for these two function (use ?AIC and ?extractAIC) this is expected.

Note that the AIC is just defined up to an additive constant, because this is also the case for the log-likelihood. This means you should check whether

```
extractAIC(full.modell) - extractAIC(null.modell)
```

and

```
AIC(full.modell) - AIC(null.modell)
```

give the same result. As long as they do, both functions are equivalent for all practical purposes.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but I still don't understand why `extractAIC(null.lm) != AIC(null.lm)` while `extractAIC(null.glm) == AIC(null.glm)` even though `null.lm` is the same model as `null.glm`. Could you expand your answer a little?

Comment: @smillig `extractAIC` uses different methods for `lm` fits and `glm` fits, i.e., `extractAIC.lm` and `extractAIC.glm`. You can use `getAnywhere` to study their code. `AIC` uses the same method for both.

Comment: I have several pairs of models (with multiple predictors) for which both functions give different results. Model 1: y = x1 + x2, Model 2: y = z + x1 + x2*z. `extractAIC()` gives lower (negative) value for Model 1, while AIC gives lower (positive) value for Model 2.

Comment: @Maxim.K You give little information on the type of variables and models used. If you did and there are some differences to this question it might be worthwhile to post this as a new question. Hard to say, without knowing the details.

Comment: @Erik I doubt it will be worth much if I say that z is continuous and x2 is categorical (dummified). One would need the data to reproduce and I cannot publish them I'm afraid.