# AIC - different values based on different R functions

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting

I am a beginner in the whole forecasting/regression/time-series topic. While reading "Forecasting: principles and practice" from *Rob J Hyndman* and
*George Athana­sopou­los* i found something strange.

```
library(fpp)
test <- tslm(ausbeer ~ trend+season)
#summary(test)
#plot(ausbeer, col='grey')
#lines(fitted(test), col='red')
AIC(test)
> 2327.316
CV(test)
      CV          AIC         AICc          BIC        AdjR2 
3582.0767318 1728.5234412 1728.9352059 1748.6345900    0.5377408
```

Why is there a difference in the AIC values (Akaike's Information Criterion)? As far as i understood `AIC(test)` and the AIC value in the `CV(test)` should be the same.

Comment: It's very common for different packages/computations to include/exclude different constant terms in the AIC ...

Comment: So in order to use AIC for comparing different models i have to take care that i use always the same AIC function!?

Comment: the difference is between `extractAIC()` (used by `CV()`) which leaves out a constant term, and `AIC()`, which appears to give a computation consistent with the full Normal log-likelihood expression.

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-December/147855.html ; http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43733/what-is-the-difference-between-aic-and-extractaic-in-r

Answer (score 2):

> It's very common for different packages/computations to
>   include/exclude different constant terms in the AIC. Here, the
>   difference is between extractAIC() (used by CV()) which leaves out a
>   constant term, and AIC(), which appears to give a computation
>   consistent with the full Normal log-likelihood expression. Also see [What is the difference between AIC() and extractAIC() in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43733/what-is-the-difference-between-aic-and-extractaic-in-r) and https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-December/147855.html

Comment: I've copied this comment by @BenBolker as a community wiki answer because the comment is, more or less, an answer to this question. We have a dramatic gap between answers and questions. At least part of the problem is that some questions are answered in comments: if comments which answered the question were answers instead, we would have fewer unanswered questions.