# Calculating AIC for a linear regression model

Tags: r, linear-model, likelihood, aic

I'm seeing some "inconsistencies" on how R calculates the Akaike Information Criterion (AIC) for linear regression models. I'd like to get its expression so I can calculate it myself. The issues I'm referring to can be seen here:

```
complex_model <- lm(mpg~hp+wt, mtcars)
simple_model <- lm(mpg~hp, mtcars)
AIC(complex_model)
AIC(simple_model)
step(complex_model)
```

The difference in AIC between both models stay the same, however the values don't. I understand that for all practical effect in model selection this doesn't change much, but why is the results different? What expressions are these values obtained from?

Comment: See the discussion on AIC: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/524258/why-does-the-akaike-information-criterion-aic-sometimes-favor-an-overfitted-mo/524311#524311

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this answer:

[What is the difference between AIC() and extractAIC() in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43733/what-is-the-difference-between-aic-and-extractaic-in-r)

I discovered this by inspecting the code of the step() function, looking at the help for extractAIC() and, finding that confusing, searching CrossValidated.